# Excel VBA : Compare Values Within a column for all other rows having same identification key in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a jumbled time series data as I have shown above in the first image. What I want to do is to check and flag is some of the keys do not change value over time.

Actual Data

[image: Image 1- Actual Data]

First I tried splitting the data for every unique key as separate time series into different worksheets but I have over 17k unique keys so rather impossible to split them as individual worksheets and process them all due to ram issues.

To explain the situation better, for example as you can see for the key - **123abc** in column A, I have different values in **some number** (column C) at different points in time(column B).(Image 2)

No static values

[image: Image 2 - No static values]

But in the case of key - **431iow** the values in **some number**(column C) was same for 3 consecutive quarters. (Image 3)

Some static values

[image: Image 3 - Some static values]

I would want to try and flag the rows which didn't change over last quarter, and leave others blank and add this flag variable as a new column.(Image 4)

Flags/Desired Outcome

[image: Image 4 - Flags/Desired Outcome]

And also make a consolidated file with unique entries from Column A with just flags as shown in Image 5.

Flag/Desired result

[image: Image 5 - Flag/Desired result]

Can someone help me with this very specific issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you run into trouble? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Start by sorting the data on Column A and a concatenation of C,D,+ E as strings. Then it'll be easy to just iterate through all rows in a single pass. You need to try stuff in VBA and show us what you've tried

Comment: Are you only checking `some number` for stability?  What about `other number` and `another number`?  I would think this could be done easily in Power Query where you can group by key and then examine the relevant number columns.

Comment: Sorry everyone who might have had the same issue but the file I was working with was simply too big to be handled by excel and it would often result in crash. I initially tried just splitting the file into several sheets but it didn't work either cause I can't make 24k sheets at once without running into a crash. I tried the concatenate route as well but also was of no use. I have moved to R and am using time series library there to find stationarity and remove static values. Thanks everyone for the help!